# jsZip for dynamic values in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have multiple files and I want to compress them into one folder. I got a package named jsZip in *reactjs* and I have used that. Below is my code:

```
const zipDownload =() => {
const zip = new JSZip();

let folder = zip.folder('collection');
  if(this.state.final_downloaded.includes("DZ")) {
  folder.file(`${"Facility-" + getCurrentDate()}.csv`, this.state.csv_gcs);
  } 
  /* Generate a zip file asynchronously and trigger the download */
  folder.generateAsync({type:"blob"}).then(function(content) {
    // see FileSaver.js
    saveAs(content, "Reports.zip");
    });
    }
```

I got it compressed as a zip but the file is empty. It has no data.

```
generate_download_csv_data_facility() {
let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userDetail"));
var fac = this.state.facilities;
var gen_fac = [];
if (fac.length > 0) {
  for (var i = 0; i < fac.length; i++) {
    gen_fac.push({
      "Name":fac[i].facility_name,
      "Country":fac[i].country,
      "Address": fac[i].address,
      "City": fac[i].city,
      "State":fac[i].facility_state,
      "Postal Code":fac[i].postal_code,
      "TimeZone":fac[i].facility_timezone,
    });
}
  } else {
    gen_fac.push({
      "Name": "N/A",
      "Country": "N/A",
      "Address": "N/A",
      "City": "N/A",
      "State": "N/A",
      "Postal Code": "N/A",
      "TimeZone": "N/A",
    });
} 

this.setState({ csv_gcs: gen_fac,
organization_id: user.organization_id });
```

}

Above is the data I want to display in a csv file. Any suggestions?